# special character in column name

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2008-r2, special-characters

I am dealing with a table where some columns have special character in it.
I am creating view by concatenating column names in a string and while executing it, it is giving error as 'Invalid column name' at execution statement.I tried with escaping those with escape character but it didn't worked. Tried '&' as an escaping character for '&' in column name.
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"? Are you prefixing your string with `N'`? Can you post the sql for the view creation?

Comment: `table.[funky&name]`?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin I have some ampersands and some single quotes in column names. Tried using N', but of no use.

Comment: OK, I thought you were having unicode characters. Then the square brackets should solve your issue.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Tried square brackets too! Not working!!

Comment: If you want us to help, you have to post your query. Feel free to change column names if they are secret, just leave special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the special characters, you might be able to resolve this by putting square brackets around the column names:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.result([!"£$%^&*()] int,[{}:@~#';'] varchar(50),[<>?/.,] int)
```

You can use the `QUOTENAME` function for this purpose:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('!"£$%^&*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give detail ? which are these special characters ?

You can put column names inside **[ ]**